# BeautifulSoup scraping certain word

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Just to clarify everything, I'm new to Python and trying to scrape data using BeautifulSoup. The problem is, how do I scrape certain words in a middle of a sentence? Below is the HTML that I try to scrape:

```
<div data-testid="search-result" class="sc-iYUSvU crSfLY">
     Found <b data-testid="total">2625</b> All Properties in Kelantan - Page 1 of 66
</div>
```

I just want to get the number after *Page 1 of*. I try to do it using regex and find it according to the class name but it fails. Note that, the number may differ according to the property listing on the website. The regex I tried was:

```
All Properties in [^ ]+ - Page (\d+) of (\d+)
```

Comment: What regex did you try?

Comment: Can you try the regex `All Properties in [^ ]+ - Page (\d+) of (\d+)` ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to find the tag by it's text "Page", and then `split()` to access the last index `[-1]`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<div data-testid="search-result" class="sc-iYUSvU crSfLY">
     Found <b data-testid="total">2625</b> All Properties in Kelantan - Page 1 of 66
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(
    soup.find(lambda tag: "Page" in tag.text).text.split()[-1]
)
```

Output:

```
66
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to find the number by using the class name sc-iYUSvU crSfLY? Because I try the code you give but it displays other output.

Comment: @AhmadNasaiei Try `soup.find(lambda tag: "Page" in tag.text and "sc-iYUSvU crSfLY" in t.attrs).text.split()[-1]`